# C# Encoding.UTF8 messing up the bytes[]

Tags: c#, utf-8, character-encoding

I am facing very strange problem in which I have byte[] and when I am passing this to Convert.UTF8.GetString(byte[] bytes) method, the system encoding is messing with my bytes and replacing only few special bytes (which I am using as Markers in my system) to some three char string representation.

```
[0] 70  byte
[1] 49  byte
[2] 45  byte
[3] 86  byte
[4] 49  byte
[5] 253 byte     <-- Special byte
[6] 70  byte
[7] 49  byte
[8] 45  byte
[9] 86  byte
[10]50  byte
[11]253 byte     <-- Special byte
[12]70  byte
[13]49  byte
[14]45  byte
[15]86  byte
[16]51  byte
```

When I am passing above byte[] into Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes) method I am getting following output;

```
private Encoding _encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8", new EncoderReplacementFallback("?"), new DecoderReplacementFallback("?"));       
_encoding.GetString(bytes)  "F1-V1�F1-V2�F1-V3" string
```

Actual value should not have '�' as this means it failed to encode and replaced those special bytes with '�'. Is there anyway I can get around this i.e. convert to string and keep the special bytes representation to a single char.

I have following special bytes which I am trying to use as markers;

```
byte AM = (byte) 254
byte VM = (byte) 253
byte SM = (byte) 252
```

Your help and comments will be appreciated.

Thanks,

--

Sheeraz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is only UTF-8 **between** the markers, so if it were me I would be extracting the delimited portions **first**, and then UTF-8 decode each portion separately, i.e. read through the `byte[]` looking for the markers in your **binary** data, giving you 3 binary chunks (70,49,45,86,49; 70,49,45,86,50; 70,59,45,86,51) which are then decoded into 3 strings. You can't UTF-8 decode the entire binary sequence because **it is not valid UTF-8**.

However, personally, I would say that using a delimiter is dangerous here; I would probably go for a length-prefix approach, so that

- I know that I'm not accidentally conflating delimiters and real data
- I can process it more efficiently than byte-by-byte

For example, if we used a "varint" length prefix, that would be:

```
05,70,49,45,86,49,05,70,49,45,86,50,05,70,59,45,86,51
```

where the `05` is the "varint" length which we interpret as 5 bytes; this means we can process nicely:

```
// pseude code
while(!EOF) {
    int len = ReadVarint();
    var blob = ReadBytes(len);
    string s = Utf8Decode(blob);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... I have to do it manually because the requirement is to have everything in UTF-8 encoded as my DB is UTF-8 only. I now I am not converting anything into String but working on bytes only.

Comment: @SJunejo k, but please note: your current strategy **is not UTF-8**. Your database would be entirely within its rights to explode at you.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use those special values as markers inside a UTF-8 string, because the string ends up being invalid according to the UTF-8 [encoding rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

You *could* sneakily insert them and then take them back out *before* the data is fed to UTF-8-aware code like `Encoding.GetString`, but that's not a good idea exactly because it's sneaky (*way* confusing to anyone who does not already know what voodoo is happening in there, and thus *very* counter-productive).

A more sane option would be to simply insert "special" UTF-8 encoded characters inside your string. This would technically require (especially if you pick a character that encodes to 1 byte as those would be more likely to occur inside your actual payload as well) that you also come up with a scheme to *escape* these characters when they occur naturally inside your payload.

Comment: +1 If you need markers like this then you could pick a character somewhere inside Unicode to use instead, e.g. in one of the private ranges, and then use valid UTF-8 encodings of those characters as markers. But they'll be more than one byte each. Or chop the byte stream around your markers ahead of time and then convert each valid section to Unicode at a time, but you'd need to be careful to not actually pick up genuine UTF-8 encodings using those bytes - i.e. you'd effectively be writing your own decoder.